# Is there ever any reason to respond with "Vary: *" and "Vary: Foo" for the same resource?

Tags: http, caching, proxy, rfc2616, vary

Is there any reason for a HTTP server to sometimes respond with `Vary: *`, and sometimes with `Vary: Foo`, to requests for the same resource?

What should a cache do, if after receiving  (and caching) both responses, it then receives a request with a matching `Foo` header, for which the `Vary: Foo` response is suitable?  Can it serve the matching response, or does the separate `Vary: *` response override it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each response is evaluated in isolation, so it can select the Vary: Foo response.

See:

- https://svn.tools.ietf.org/svn/wg/httpbis/draft-ietf-httpbis/latest/p6-cache.html#constructing.responses.from.caches
- https://svn.tools.ietf.org/svn/wg/httpbis/draft-ietf-httpbis/latest/p6-cache.html#caching.negotiated.responses

Answer (score 0):

There may be a situation where a server can guarantee that for a certain time a resource's representation is only influenced by `Foo` but after some time have elapsed, it can no longer make any guarantee and must set the header to `Vary: *`.

Expiration is preferred over validation. Since `Vary: *` forces revalidation, the cache should select the `Foo` response assuming it is fresh.